# Iterating through HL7 message using Segment Iterator Object of Chameleon Python API

Tags: python, iterator, hl7

I am generating HL7 messages using Interfaceware Iguana and Chameleon. This is my first experience with Python, so this question may be immature. I am trying to iterate through message using Segment Iterator Object.

```
current_segment = environment.input_segment_iterator()  
current_segment.apply_transform()
output = current_segment.output()
if current_segment.move_next('OBX'):
    log('OBX setId is ' + current_segment.field(1).value );
```

I have written this script in global post process equation window, but it always gives me an error saying

```
RuntimeError: Invalid iterator must be reset before being used while calling apply_transform
while executing the outgoing post process equation for the project.
```

I have seen many examples of using iterator, and all follow same pattern. How do I reset this iterator, and why is this invalid?

After doing some research work, I discovered that I cannot use `input_segment_iterator` in the `post process` equation window, but in `transformation` window. Now I am able to see changes I make to script using the `Test Mapping` feature of Chameleon. But how can I configure this change to be implemented on each message which I generate using this `vmd`?

I think someone working with INTERFACEWARE Chameleon and Iguana products could easily help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Not much of an Iguana person, But what I believe is you are missing this

`current_segment.reset()` after you are done iterating through OBX, so that it sets the current segment to MSH.

You can see sample usage on [this page](http://www.interfaceware.com/manual/splitmsg_tut_step_3.html).

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer but I did use this method after my iteration or even before apply_transform() method, but nothing worked out. As far as I think it gives this error before even starting iteration, at the very spot I start its usage
`current_segment.apply_transform()`

Comment: Okay can you move the `current_segment.apply_transform()`under your `if current_segment.move_next('OBX'):` line and try or even remove it and see?

Comment: tried it already, it starts giving error on `current_segment.output()`. I think there is something more to do before start using this iterator but every sample example using it like I did